# Abrir ajustes wifi mediante href

Tags: javascript, android, href

Me gustaría abrir los ajustes de Wifi desde un enlace href o desde javascript.
He buscado información al respecto tanto en google como aquí, pero no encuentro nada.

Me refiero a algo como esto:

```
<a href="android://settings.wifi">Ajustes Wifi</a>
```

Comment: Dudo mucho que android permita que código web habrá funcionalidades core del teléfono

Comment: @solamente en este caso no sería realizar un cambio, si desea solo abrir los settings se puede realizar mediante un Intent, en el caso de Wifi mediante:   startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys De la forma que lo ha comentado me ha parecido que su intención era interactuar desde una web publica a dispositivos privados.

Comment: Como bien dice @solamente lo que quiero es que al acceder a una web en cuestión de mi servidor, esta le mande al dispositivo android la orden de abrir los ajustes wifi para que el usuario elija la red. Aunque lo que quería en un principio (que es imposible) es mandarle al dispositivo los parámetros y que se conecte automáticamente, luego poner esa url en un código qr y con escanear el código, se conectaría el empleado o la visita a la red wifi sin necesidad de introducir ssid ni password. Pero me parece que voy a tener que buscar otra opción para optimizar este proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Define un [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) a tu `WebView` y sobre escribe el método `onLoadResource()`, aquí puedes detectar la url que intentas cargar, en este caso lo definido en `href` que es "android://settings.wifi" y realizas el Intent para abrir la configuración de Wifi.

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    //Define WebView Client
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);

            //Si la url que intenta cargar es igual a "android://settings.wifi", realiza una acción.
            if(url.equals("android://settings.wifi")){

                //Abre settings 
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

            }
        }
    });

    //Carga página que contiene el href
    webView.loadUrl("http://prueba.juanjo.com/mypage.html ");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorgesys por tu completa respuesta, pero eso es programación en JAVA, para realizarlo a través de una apk y yo estoy buscando hacerlo a través de JavaScript en una web. Pero muchas gracias!